Chrome or Edge keyboard shortcut to search for or switch between groups like you can with tabs
In Edge and Chrome browsers, you can cycle to the tab to the right with ctrl + tab or to the left with ctrl + shift + tab. You can also bring up a tab search menu with ctrl + shift + a and type in text to search in tab names. Are there similar shortcuts for switching between tab groups? Whether it's cycling through groups like ctrl + tab or being able to search for a group by a name like ctrl + shift + a.
